# .classname element needs mousemove event even when the cursor is not on top of them. How to get event to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the mousemove event when the cursor is not on top of the element itself?

This is what I currently have:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '.className', OnMouseMove);

function OnMouseMove(e) {
    var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
    var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
    var offsetCoords = "( " + e.offsetX + ", " + e.offsetY + " )";

    console.log('clientCoords: '+clientCoords+', pageCoords: '+pageCoords+', offsetCoords: '+offsetCoords);
}
```

I have a lot of elements using the .className that I will be adding animations to but I need the mouse coordinates even when the cursor is not on top of the elements. How can I do this?

Comment: Bind to `document` without event delegation.

Comment: I want stuff to happen on every element that has .className based on the mouse coordinates.

Comment: @rotaercz: That's fine, you can do that in the handler, but if you want to receive `mousemove` events when the cursor isn't over any of them, you have to capture it on something the cursor *is* over. `document` is your best option, most likely.

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have in your question?

Comment: @philtune: I don't get mouse coordinates when I'm not on top of the elements.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're targetting `.className` when you should be checking `mousemove` on the whole `$(document)` altogether.

Comment: The point isn't purely about the mousemove coordinates. I also need .classname to do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the elements in the mouse move function.

```js
$(function(){

    $(document).on( "mousemove", MouseMove );

    var cachedElems = $( '.tracker' );

    function MouseMove(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX,
            pageY = e.pageY;

        $.each(cachedElems, function(i,elem){
            elem = $(elem);

            var elemX = pageX - elem.offset().left,
                elemY = pageY - elem.offset().top;

            $(elem).text(
                'page x: ' + pageX + '\n' +
                'page y: ' + pageY + '\n' +
                '\n' +
                'elem x: ' + elemX + '\n' +
                'elem y: ' + elemY + '\n'
            );

        });
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f1Lzqxom/

Comment: This looks close to what I'm looking for. I tried this, var cursorDistanceY = Math.abs(elem.position().top - e.clientY);
      
        console.log('cursorDistanceY ('+i+') ('+elem+'):' +cursorDistanceY); Doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I am loading the page with the .classname elements later after the javascript loads. Could this stop it from working?

Comment: @rotaercz - Updated to get the position relative to each element.

Comment: @rotaercz - You don't *have* to cache the elements, but it won't scale well if you have to search the DOM for those elements *every time the mouse moves*. The exact caching strategy you use depends on your needs and constraints.

Comment: cachedElems is empty. I think this is this because I'm loading the content with the .classname elements via ajax? But I'm not sure how I'm supposed to populate cachedElems.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('mousemove', OnMouseMove);
```

That will get you the event based on the document. 
That's the only way to get it no matter where it is.
You can then check to see if it's over a specific element, maybe with a hover on the .classname elements to toggle a booleaen or something.

Like

```
var isOverElement = false;
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.classname', function(e){
    isOverElement = true;
}).on('mouseleave', '.classname', function(e){
    isOverElement = false;
});
```

HTH,
-Ted

EDITING to add additional code samples requested from comments...

To add elements to the **cachedElems** array, you need to add some code to whatever code is adding them to the page, or redefine the array.

The array would need to be declared globally, or at least in a context each function can get to it.

Such as

```
<script>
var cachedElems;

$(document).ready(....
```

Then in whatever function is adding the elements, or loading a page with those elements, on load complete, define the array, like:

```
cachedElems = $('.className');
```

Comment: So how does my .className elements get the coordinates?

Comment: Hard to say exactly without really understanding what you're doing...Possible you could set and update the coordinates as global variables--or at least outside the scope of the OnMouseMove function, so that the mouse enter/leave functions could read those values and do something with them

Comment: The other person's answer is a lot closer to what I'm looking for. However when I check the console, I'm not getting an output on his answer. Could you take a look?

Comment: Just to be sure, you have that code wrapped in a doc-ready function, yes? His sample works fine for me...

Comment: Yes, it is in $(document).ready(function(){
    test();
}); test() being all of the other person's answer.

Comment: The page itself with the .classname elements are loaded later. Is this stopping it from working?

Comment: a jsfiddle would be really helpful. Yes, that could be part of it--it works fine for me as to logging the coords to the console. The array 'cachedElems' would definitely be empty if they were added after that function ran...

Comment: So how can I populate cachedElems with the new page elements? (I would do a jsfiddle but it's a new page that gets loaded.)

Comment: The can be pushed into that array, or that array can simply be redefined once they are all on the page--if they're all added at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, it worked! I really appreciate the help but the other person's answer was closer to what I needed.

Comment: I upthumbed your answer though.